# Как в unity создать создать внутреннюю не зависимую сеть наподобие интернета

Tags: c#, unity3d, сеть

Я создаю игру на unity в которой нужно прохожить уровни с помощью программирования то есть, надо подключаться с помощью типо терминала windows или termux на android и тд

Ну и мне надо как то реализовать такую логику как реальный интернет: dns-сервера, маршрутизаторы, протоколы и всякая такая хрень но с минимальным и приближенным кодом (мне просто надо чтобы игрок с помощью скрипта мог подключаться к другим похожим (например на игроке скрипт Device и на объекте другом допустим тоже Device и мне надо как и куда то подключиться как в меню где вайфай но если в реальности обнаружение происходит по радиоволнам или чем то таким то как в игре это реализовать))

У меня есть интерфейсы ICellular, IHotspot, IWirelessFidelity, и мне нужно в них что то реализовать но что я не могу понять хоть и работал с python socket а типо делать подключиьься, отключиться для всех я думаю точно не стоит

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в unity создать имитацию сети интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540681/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-unity-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: А за пересоздание закрытых вопросов вы рискуете получить люлей от автоматической банилки

Comment: ну по факту ту это другой вопрос же да и тело сообщения отличается (просто мне кажется тот вопрос открывать сразу не собирались и ждать пришлось бы)